# Getting Error: Instruments crashed on startup at Instruments.onInstrumentsExit - when trying to open appium inspector

Tags: ios, appium

I am getting error when trying to open `Appium Inspector` :

```
Error: Instruments crashed on startup
    at Instruments.onInstrumentsExit (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:398:31)
```

**I am using Xcode 5 and appium - 1.0 and MAC OS X 10.9.**

Please help .

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the UI Automation on the real device, to do this go to:

> **Settings > Developer > Enable UI Automation**

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am getting this error when I am trying to do it on Simulator :(

Comment: Try the same for simulator, not sure. I had faced the same, while moving on to iOS 8 with device and this had worked for me at that time.

Comment: Can you please tell me which option we need to select for Force Device & Platform Version .Also I am not able to find Developer option under Settings on the Simulator.